# How to store lat-lon geolocation point in a document for GAE search?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

There where indications in the [GoogleIO talk on Search API](http://youtu.be/7B7FyU9wW8Y?t=26m10s) that we can do searches based on geolocation.

I can't find an [appropriate field](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/fieldclasses) to store location info.

How can I store geolocation info in the [document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/documentclass) so I could issue queries based on distance from a particular GPS location?

Comment: I don't believe there is a good answer to this.  At the moment, the Search API is in an Experimental state.  I've search through the documentation and the sample code(http://goo.gl/Yb7n1).  There isn't much information that is available that either addresses this functionality, or allows you to construct a good mechanism for solving this problem.  I recommend checking out the Search API's issue tracker page (http://goo.gl/LczvP).  Someone has requested this functionality and it is currently ranked #3 (http://goo.gl/SIDqA) in the list of issues.

Comment: I think so myself, but I wasn't sure. The Google IO talk is somewhat misleading there is [mention of GeoPoint](http://youtu.be/7B7FyU9wW8Y?t=12m30s) but there is no such field. I did not know it was not released yet or API implementation have changed.

Answer (score 7):

On June 28, 2012, Google integrated the [GeoPoint class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/geopointclass) into the Google App Engine Search API library with the specific intent of making spatial points searchable.

GeoPoints are stored as GeoFields within the Search Document.  Google provides [this support documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Performing_Location-Based_Searches) outlining the use of the GeoPoint with the Search API.

The following example declares a GeoPoint and assigns it to a GeoField in a Search Document.  These new classes provide a lot more functionality than what is listed below, but this code is a starting point for a basic understanding of how to use the new  spatial search functionality..

**Constructing a document with an associated GeoPoint**

```
## IMPORTS ##
from google.appengine.api import search

def CreateDocument(content, lat, long):
  geopoint = search.GeoPoint(lat, long)
  return search.Document(
    fields=[
            search.HtmlField(name='content', value=content),
            search.DateField(name='date', value=datetime.now().date())
            search.GeoField(name='location', value=geopoint)
           ])
```

**Searching the GeoPoint document field (Slightly modified from the Search API docs)**

```
## IMPORTS ##
from google.appengine.api import search

ndx = search.Index(DOCUMENT_INDEX)
loc = (-33.857, 151.215)

query = "distance(location, geopoint(-33.857, 151.215)) < 4500"

loc_expr = "distance(location, geopoint(-33.857, 151.215))"

sortexpr = search.SortExpression(
  expression=loc_expr,
  direction=search.SortExpression.ASCENDING, default_value=4501)

search_query = search.Query(
  query_string=query,
  options=search.QueryOptions(
    sort_options=search.SortOptions(expressions=[sortexpr])))

results = index.search(search_query)
```